# Javascript jquery to contact an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to connect to a webapi at a location that looks like this from inside my js jquery file.

example.com/?var=input

Is there a simpler way to do it than an ajax call?

Comment: can you please explain what are you doing? what contact API?

Comment: @balexandre, I need to contact a webpage, supply it this input var=input, and receive a response. I can do it with ajax, but are there easier ways? Thanks.

Comment: can you do it with ajax? from a different domain?

Comment: @Vitor Yes you can, as long as you use a proxy class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use AJAX for this, but I guess you could open a hidden IFRAME with the URL set to the page you want to connect to (not sure why you would do this though!).

Maybe use a JavaScript library like JQuery to make life easier?

If the data you're trying to access is returned as JSON then you can get around the browser security problems.

Here is a JQuery example where a request is made to Flickr.com from JQuery.com:

[docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback)

Answer (score 1):

You may be run into cross domain issues if you do it with an ajax call.
Call the web-api from serverside, it would be the most appropriate way.

Comment: This page explains it quite well: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html